# Selenium Python,default profile is not loading after using ChromeDriverManager().install()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, profile, webdrivermanager-python

After switching to ChromeDriverManager().install(),I am not able to use default profile.Any workaround there so that I can avoid logging in every time?

*driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),....)*

used many solutions found here, but still not working.
directories:
user-data-dir=C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
user-data-dir=C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Answer (score 0):

To use the default profile, you have to mention the path like below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()

# path of the chrome profile's parent directory
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
# name of the directory
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

Comment: Not working

aise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Users\Developer\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:

Comment: Before executing the code, close all of the chrome browser windows and try, because you are running chrome with default profile, if it is already opened, it will be crashed.